# How to convert between Options with Into?

Tags: rust, option-type

I have in my project a struct `A` which is logically related to a struct `B` from a different crate. Both have internally an optional sub-struct (`C` / `D`).

Let's say for this example they have this struct definition:

```rust
struct D {
    name: Option<String>
}

struct B {
    spec: Option<D>
}

struct C {
    name: Option<String>
}

struct A {
    spec: Option<C>
}
```

Now I want to implement the `Into`-trait on `A` into `B`:

```rust
impl Into<D> for C {
    fn into(self) -> D {
        D {
            name: self.name
        }
    }
}

impl Into<B> for A {
    fn into(self) -> B {
        B {
            spec: self.spec.into()
        }
    }
}
```

But rust does not allow it:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::option::Option<D>: From<std::option::Option<C>>` is not satisfied
   --> src\model\k8s.rs:615:29
    |
615 |             spec: self.spec.into()
    |                             ^^^^ the trait `From<std::option::Option<C>>` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<D>`
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <std::option::Option<&'a T> as From<&'a std::option::Option<T>>>
              <std::option::Option<&'a mut T> as From<&'a mut std::option::Option<T>>>
              <std::option::Option<&'a tracing_core::span::Id> as From<&'a tracing::span::EnteredSpan>>
              <std::option::Option<&'a tracing_core::span::Id> as From<&'a tracing::span::Span>>
            and 10 others
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<std::option::Option<D>>` for `std::option::Option<C>`
```

Although I provide a custom implementation for `Into` on `C` it only checks for `From`. Which I can't provide as `D` is another crate. I have to write this:

```rust
spec: if let Some(v) = self.spec { Some(v.into()) } else { None }
```

Now the question: Is there a better way I am missing? If not, why is it such a hassle to `into()` Options?

Comment: Are `A` and `C` defined in your crate, while `B` and `D` defined in another crate?

Comment: @Sven: Yes, A & C are my own Code, B & D is what I need for the lib I use

Comment: Related: [When should I implement From vs Into?](/q/29812530/2189130) - always choose to implement `From` since the blanket implementation for `Into` will let you call `.into()` if it implements `From`, but not the reverse.

Comment: Related: [How to convert the inner value in an Option?](/q/62152734/2189130)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you're calling `Into::into` on the `Option<C>` type rather than the type the `Option` holds (`C`).

You can use the [`Option::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map) method which operates on the inner type of the `Option`:

```
impl Into<B> for A {
    fn into(self) -> B {
        B {
            spec: self.spec.map(Into::into)
        }
    }
}
```

There is no blanket `impl<T, U: Into<T>> Into<Option<T>> for Option<U>` (or the `From` equivalent) in the standard library, that's why you can't use `Into` trait to turn `Option<T>` into `Option<U>` directly on the `Option` and have to rely on `Option::map` or some other way (like your last snippet) of extracting the inner type instead.